# Get size of group KineticJS

Tags: html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have trouble in my kineticjs.

How can I get `getHeight()` and `getWidht()` from my group that contains two rectangle?

Here's my code:

```
var mygrup=new Kinetic.Group({
name:"mygrup",


draggable:true  
})

layer.draw()

var tool= new Kinetic.Rect({
       width: 50,
      height: 20,
      x:0,
      y:20,
      fill: '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6),

      name:"image",

    });
var tool1= new Kinetic.Rect({
       width: 50,
      height: 20,
      x:0,
      y:0,
      fill: '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6),

      name:"image",


    });
mygrup.add(tool1).add(tool)
```

Comment: As I see in source you can't get width in this way "mygrup.getWidth()". This code always return 0. So you should calculate values manually.

Comment: a group can have a width, but you are using it as just a container, so there is no width.

Answer (score 3):

```
  var children = mygrup.getChildren();
  var width = 0;
  for( var i=0; i< children.length; i++){
      if(children[i].getWidth() > width)
          width = children[i].getWidth(); 
  }
```

this gets the maximum width of any element, but the important part is the getting all children of the group and then iterating through them. You can sum the widths, or you can get all the x values and take the furthest left one and the furthest right one and make that your width. Or something else.

Comment: And that assumes that all elements are neatly aligned. What about elements overlapping or with gap between them ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a better approach is to just iterate through all of the children and find the minX, minY, and maxX and maxY by taking into account shape widths.  The width and height of the group would then be:

var width = maxX - minX;
var height = maxY - minY;

group.getWidth() and group.getHeight(), if implemented in the future, would take a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

Nested (recursive) solution to SoluableNonagon's implementation

```
function getMaxWidth(root_node){

   var min_x = Number.MAX_VALUE //window.innerWidth(),
       max_x = 0;


   var maxWidth = function recur(node){
       var children = node.getChildren();

       if (children.length === 0) 
           return node.getAbsoluteX();


       for(var i=0; i< children.length; i++){
           var pos = recur(children[i]);

           if (pos > max_x) max_x = pos;
           else if (pos < min_x) min_x = pos;
       }
   }

   return maxWidth(root_node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution takes in account elements that overlap as well as element with gaps between them (when they are not touching).
It also returns the x/y location (because I needed it).

```js
getGroupSize = function (pGroup) {
    var minX = Number.MAX_VALUE,
        maxX = 0,
        minY = Number.MAX_VALUE,
        maxY = 0;
    var children = pGroup.getChildren();
    if (children.length === 0) {
        minX = pGroup.getX();
        maxX = minX + pGroup.width();
        minY = pGroup.getY();
        maxY = minY + pGroup.height();
    }
    else {
        var groupX = pGroup.getX();
        var groupY = pGroup.getY();
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            var size = this.getGroupSize(children[i]);
            size.minX += groupX;
            size.maxX += groupX;
            size.minY += groupY;
            size.maxY += groupY;
            if (size.minX < minX) {
                minX = size.minX;
            }
            if (size.maxX > maxX) {
                maxX = size.maxX;
            }
            if (size.minY < minY) {
                minY = size.minY;
            }
            if (size.maxY > maxY) {
                maxY = size.maxY;
            }
        }
    }
    return { minX: minX, maxX: maxX, minY: minY, maxY: maxY, width: maxX - minX, height: maxY - minY };
};
```